# Why git clean -f does not remove all the untracked files?

Tags: git, git-clean

I hit this today:

```
% git checkout another_branch
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        __version__.txt
        alembic.ini
        alembic/README
        alembic/env.py
        alembic/script.py.mako
        folder1/file1
        folder2/file2
        ....
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

OK, so I'll remove untracked files:

```
% git clean -f
Not removing alembic/
Not removing tools/maintenance/
```

However, it seems that not all untracked files have been removed:

```
% git checkout another_branch
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        alembic/README
        alembic/env.py
        alembic/script.py.mako
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

What's weird is that at first `git checkout another_branch` git knew about those particular untracked files it later complained about (`alembic/README`, `alembic/env.py`, `alembic/script.py.mako`).

So why git did not delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kind of untracked files: untracked files and ignored files.

When running as `git clean` (`-f` is just to override a "safety" config option), git will only remove untracked files, when running as `git clean -x` it will remove both untracked and ignored files.

For the checkout issue, it is probably triggered by different `.gitignore` files in the two branches.

Answer (score 1):

Do the directories contain `.git` subdirectories or files?

> -f, --force
>
> If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git
>              clean will refuse to delete files or directories unless given -f, -n or -i. Git
>              will refuse to delete directories with .git sub directory or file unless a second
>              -f is given. This affects also git submodules where the storage area of the
>              removed submodule under .git/modules/ is not removed until -f is given twice.

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem I had, and this is the command which finally worked: `git clean -f -f -d -d`